# Connecting to Amazon's DynamoDB inside a container

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-dynamodb, containers, aws-sdk

I'm tryng to setup a local environment with **node** and **dynamoDB**, but **I can't connect inside my app container** to DynamoDB container.

It works with nodemon but not with 2 containers.

I exposed needed ports and I add needed environment variables but I keep having this **error** :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnec
```

Here is my `Docker` file :

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=24534
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=33535

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

EXPOSE 3000
```

And here my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
      - .env:/usr/src/app/.env

  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

My node app is up (my test endpoint works) but it doesn't work, thanks for helping.

For info here is how I'm connecting to `aws-sdk` in my node app :

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWSRegion,
  endpoint: process.env.AWSEndpoint
});
```

```
AWSRegion=eu-west-3
AWSEndpoint="http://localhost:8000"
```

Comment: When your app runs in the `app` container, then it can't reach the dynamodb via `localhost`. Try to use `dynamodb` as hostname, which is configured in the docker-compose file.

Comment: Okay now I see why I can't reach db container, so I need to links my app container with my db container right ? and should I change `AWSEndpoint` to match it ?

Comment: You don’t have to link the containers explicitly, docker-compose does that for you by putting the containers in the same network. You just have to adapt AWSEndpoint - hopefully ;-)

Answer (score 2):

So I finally achieved to access my dynamoDB container inside my app container.

`localhost` inside the app container refers to the container so I had to change in in my `.env` file :

- from `AWSEndpoint=http://localhost:8000`
- to `AWSEndpoint=http://dynamodb:8000`

By default with a `docker-compose.yml` file there is no need to define a `links` between containers because they are **by default**  on the same network : **bridge**, so these change make it works.